# Big O calculation for two data structures

Tags: big-o

If I had two data structures linked together (e.g. each node of a linked list contained an AVL tree) then when **searching** for **one** data item would the Big O efficiency be

- O(N) + O(logN) = O(N), using the most inefficient operation (the linked lists search)
  or
- O(N) * O(logN) = O(NlogN)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me understand what you are trying to ask.

you are saying that in linked list having each node,if that each node has a structure of avl tree, then what is the time complexity.

it is obviously O(nlogn)........

Comment: Is that not the time complexity for enumerating through all of the nodes within the structure? If I was just searching for one item (if I new which node of the linked list it belonged to), then would it not be O(N)? Thanks for the help

Comment: i think it is O(NlogN).but you did not mentioned that the linked list is in ascending order or descending order...Normally the linked lists will not have a property of sorted order.if it is binary search tree or avl tree it will  have the definite structure of min heap of max heap.But the linked lists will not have that property.i encourage the discussion.

Comment: the avl tree you mentioned will obey only the root of the tree which is one of the node of the linked lists.So every node of the linked list maintains the avl tree.so if there are n nodes in linked list we have n avl trees. Bu we do not know where exactly the searched item is avaialble.So O(nlogn)

Comment: if you think that my answer is giving reasonable answer to you then you can promote my answer by clicking the increasing point of my answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry about my vague explanation, I'll give it another shot - My linked list is in order, so O(N) search efficiency. Each node contains an AVL/Binary Tree, so O(logN) search efficiency. When I am searching for a specific item and I know which node of the linked list to search in would it not be O(N) + O(logN) = O(N)? I think if I was searching the AVL tree of every linked list node then it would be O(N) * O(logN) = O(NlogN) due to a nested search operation. Thanks again so much for the help.

Comment: You are exactly correct..But when you are dealing with algorithms you must be very careful about analysis.According to your assumption your answers are perfectly correct.when you type a question in algorithms be careful about usage of the words so that you tell your ideas clearly...any way You are welcome..

Comment: if you have any doubts on algorithms you can email to pratap533@gmail.com i am extremely happy to answer such questions.